# Регулярное действие по расписанию

Tags: android

Требует реализовать вызов определенной функции раз в N часов. Но если использовать допустим TimerTask то при погасании подсветки телефона он перестает выполнятся, иначе говоря работает только когда телефон не спит. Мне же нужно отслеживать постоянно, даже если телефон спит (Не выключен!).

Comment: почитай про сервисы, если обычный таймер не подходит

Comment: я знаю как работают сервисы. Сервис - это процесс который висит в системе, с чего он должен выполнять что-то в N часов. Точнее как он будет проверять?

Comment: смотреть на системное время - если прошло 4 часа от последнего события - повторить его опять

Comment: Не логично. Должно быть то - что заставит его смотреть на время :)

Comment: сервис все время смотрит на время =) ну а почему не подходит Timer()? в том же сервисе..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно добавить в манифест разрешение WAKE_LOCK

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmClock"></receiver>
```

Во-вторых, подключить AlarmManager

```
public class AlarmClock extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "SOME_TAG");

         wl.acquire();
         // TODO: Что-то делаем
         wl.release();
     }

     public void ToggleAlarm(Context context, Boolean fire)
     {
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmClock.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

         if (fire) {
             am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 3600000, pi);
         } else {
             am.cancel(pi);
         }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Запусти простенький Thread, который скажем каждые N секунд запускает какую то хрень. Примерно так:

```
public class Waiter extends Thread
{
    private static final String TAG=Waiter.class.getName();
    private long period;
    private boolean stop;

    public Waiter(long period)
    {
        this.period=period;
        stop=false;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(period);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Waiter interrupted!");
                stop=true;
                break;
            }
            //запускаем свою хрень
        }
        while(!stop);
        Log.d(TAG, "Finishing Waiter thread");
    }

    public synchronized void forceStop()
    {
        this.stop=true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)